# Pointers to speed up web app startup time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, startup

My SaaS ASP.Net MVC web app startup time is about 20 to 30 seconds.  The typical usage pattern is tied to business hours. So, when the first user in the morning browses to the home page, the page takes about 20 to 30 seconds to load.  Thereafter, performance on subsequent page loads is not a problem.

It's running on cloud-hosted infrastructure...Win2008 R2, quad core Xeon with 6GB RAM.

Any pointers as to what I can do to improve this startup time?

Comment: Is it slow when run locally? Have you tried profiling startup?

Comment: The (dev tools) profile shows about 18 odd seconds of waiting on the server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that your application is being shutdown during idle periods. Try setting up [a service](http://www.site24x7.com/index.html) to periodically make a request to your application and keep it alive.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've suspected as well. I've set up a monitor...will let you know if it made a difference.

Comment: Wow this made a world of difference! Thanks!